# Warning: Illegal string offset 'parameter' in php file

Tags: php

This error appears in index.php file

Warning: Illegal string offset 'id'
Warning: Illegal string offset 'std'

```
<?php
    global $options;
    foreach ($options as $value) {
        if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) {
            $$value['id'] = $value['std']; 
        } else {    
            $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); 
        }
    }
```

this problem appears when trying load new theme in Wordpress...

Comment: give some sample data for $option variable

Comment: Are you sure that `$options` has `id` and `std` as offsets?

Comment: Try `foreach ($options as $value) { var_dump($value); }`. Is it an `array` or a `string`?

Answer (score 5):

For the following two things:

```
$value['id']
$value['std']
```

the variable `$value` is not an array but a string. And the square brackets then are  substring access. Because the string is empty, you get the error message.

Demo: http://codepad.org/UDMtuO2x

Comment: actually i'm microsoft developer so i don't understand you, this bug appears when trying use wordpress theme, so can you repeat the correct code, thnx

Answer (score 2):

The [] binds stronger than the $$, i.e. php first evaluates `$value['id']` and then would use this value as the name/identifier for the variable variable.
Use curly braces to change the precedence.

```
<?php
$array = array('id'=>123);
$value = 'array';
echo ${$value}['id'];
```

prints `123`.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say unless we know the pattern that `$options` hold.
Try

`$value->id` instead of `$value["id"]`