# PHP: Illegal string-offset

Tags: php

My [open-source project](http://www.github.com/audith/Persephone) was working just fine, until I started to work on it after 6 month of break. Updated to latest XAMPP, and start getting tons of weird errors, one of which is as:

I have Input class, with a caller method as:

```
<?php
class Input
{
    public function __call ( $name , $arguments )
    {
        if ( !in_array( $name, array( "post", "get", "cookie", "request", "server", "env" ) ) )
        {
            throw new Exception( "Input::" . $name . "() not declared!" );
        }

        $_name_of_superglobal = "_" . strtoupper( $name );
        $_max_iteration_level_for_cleanup = in_array( $name, array( "server", "env" ) ) ? 1 : 10;

        # $arguments[0] is the index of the value, to be fetched from within the array.
        if ( !empty( $arguments[0] ) and array_key_exists( $arguments[0], $this->$name ) )
        {
            return $this->$name[ $arguments[0] ];
        }
        elseif ( !empty( $arguments[0] ) and array_key_exists( $arguments[0], $GLOBALS[ $_name_of_superglobal ] ) )
        {
            return $this->$name[ $this->clean__makesafe_key( $arguments[0] ) ] = $this->clean__makesafe_value( $GLOBALS[ $_name_of_superglobal ][ $arguments[0] ], array(), true );
        }
        elseif ( !empty( $arguments[0] ) and !array_key_exists( $arguments[0], $GLOBALS[ $_name_of_superglobal ] ) )
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( $this->_is_cleanup_done_for[ $name ] === true )
            {
                return $this->$name;
            }
            $this->_is_cleanup_done_for[ $name ] = true;
            return $this->$name = $this->clean__makesafe_recursively( $GLOBALS[ $_name_of_superglobal ], $_max_iteration_level_for_cleanup );
        }
    }
?>
```

This piece of code, works like this: you ask certain superglobal value from it, and it returns clean version of it, on-demand:

```
<?php
$input = new Input();
$server_name = $input->server("SERVER_NAME");
?>
```

Easy right? Well, after I updated PHP with XAMPP, it just doesn't work [edit: it works, with the Warning message] - error is:

```
PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'SERVER_NAME' in S:\...\kernel\input.php on line 159
```

line, which corresponds to line of code:

```
return $this->$name[ $this->clean__makesafe_key( $arguments[0] ) ] = $this->clean__makesafe_value( $GLOBALS[ $_name_of_superglobal ][ $arguments[0] ], array(), true );
```

which is stupid: `$_name_of_superglobal` = "_SERVER" there, and `$arguments[0]` = "SERVER_NAME" and overall assignment is string which gets cleaned.

WHAT MIGHT BE THE PROBLEM THERE? I am totally lost here!

Comment: Project in question is at: http://www.githib.com/audith/Persephone

Comment: You seem to be setting "SERVER_NAME" as the first parameter, corresponding to `$tims->name` rather then $arguments[0].

Comment: @bobthyasian - answered you below

Comment: @Neograph734: I'm not sure what you mean. There is no `$this->name`, it is `$this->$name`

Comment: @Shehi GitHub link returns 404. Check your link again please.

Comment: Typo again, its github, not githib: http://www.github.com/audith/Persephone

Comment: @Shehi Slow down, take a breath lol

Comment: Man, I have so many errors here, its just stupid. I will ask them later on, even ini_set() is messed up :D

Comment: Not to nit-pick, but the README demo link is dead. :/

Comment: @bobthyasian - yea, I am working on that. Just moved servers, putting files back in. Sorry mate. Will be up in 5 mins.

Comment: When I launch the script in my server (from the github source), everything seems to work fine !

Comment: Moving servers may be the issue here, not the code. Check server setup.

Comment: And if you show a `var_dump($_SERVER);` what is the result ?

Comment: It all works fine, even data gets assigned properly. Problem is: Why the hell I have that WARNING there. I hate errors in code, especially those which don't make sense.

README url is up now - http://persephone.audith.org/acp/components/modules

Comment: @GillesHemmerlé - there is /log/php-errors.log file in the package. Check that for PHP errors.
Config file is under /httpdocs, if u wanna install locally for testing. Also import sql.sql file into local MySQL-server and set Db config info as well. Lastly, fix hostname located in config file - app is hostname sensitive. App also uses Memcache - if you dont have it installed locally, change Cache setting to "diskcache" in Config file.

Comment: bookmarked to share with colleagues

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Introduction**

I know this has been answered but `Illegal string offset ERROR` is not the only issue i see here. I belive they are better ways to introduce the flexibility you want and also still make elements save without all that `complexity` and using of `$GLOBALS`.

You can start by looking at :

- [Are global variables in PHP considered bad practice? If so, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557787/are-global-variables-in-php-considered-bad-practice-if-so-why)
- [PHP global in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166087/php-global-in-functions)
- [Why global state is the devil, and how to avoid using it](http://tomnomnom.com/posts/why-global-state-is-the-devil-and-how-to-avoid-using-it)

**Quick Review**

```
$input = new Input();                          <-- You add to initiate a class 
$server_name = $input->server("SERVER_NAME");
      ^                  ^           ^
      |                  |           |
    variable             |           |
                     Variable        |
                                  Variable
```

***Am not sure what stops you from just using***

```
    $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = makeSave($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
                                  ^
                                  |- I guess this is what you want to introduce
```

**Assumption - You want fexibility**

Lest assume you want flexibility and also recursion then your class call can be as flexible as :

```
print_r($input->SERVER_NAME);            |
print_r($input['SERVER_NAME']);          |----- Would Produce same result 
print_r($input->SERVER_NAME());          |
```

If this is the kind of flexibility you want the i would consider you combine `__get` , `__call` and `ArrayAccess` altogether ...

**Lets Imagine**

```
$var = array();
$var["name"] = "<b>" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "</b>";
$var["example"]['xss'] = '<IMG SRC=javascript:alert("XSS")>';
$var["example"]['sql'] = "x' AND email IS NULL; --";
$var["example"]['filter'] = "Let's meet  4:30am Ât the \tcafé\n";

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = $var ; // Just for example
```

**Now back to your format**

```
$makeSave = new MakeSafe(MakeSafe::SAVE_XSS | MakeSafe::SAVE_FILTER);
$input = new Input($_SERVER, $makeSafe);

//You can 
print_r($input->SERVER_NAME);

//Or
print_r($input['SERVER_NAME']);

//Or
print_r($input->SERVER_NAME());
```

[They would all output](http://eval.in/10975)

```
Array
(
    [0] => &lt;b&gt;localhost&lt;/b&gt;
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => &lt;IMG SRC=javascript:alert(&quot;XSS&quot;)&gt;
            [1] => x&#039; AND email IS NULL; --
            [2] => Let&#039;s meet  4:30am &#195;&#130;t the &#9;caf&#195;&#169;&#10;
        )

)
```

[See Live DEMO](http://eval.in/10975)

**Your INPUT class modified**

```
class INPUT implements \ArrayAccess {
    private $request = array();
    private $makeSafe;

    public function __construct(array $array, MakeSafe $makeSafe) {
        $this->request = $array;
        $this->makeSave = $makeSafe;
    }

    function __get($offset) {
        return $this->offsetGet($offset);
    }

    function __call($offset, $value) {
        return $this->offsetGet($offset);
    }

    public function setRequest(array $array) {
        $this->request = $array;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        trigger_error("Error: SUPER GLOBAL data cannot be modified");
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->request[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->request[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return isset($this->request[$offset]) ? $this->makeSave->parse($this->request[$offset]) : null;
    }
}
```

**Make your Save method a class**

```
class MakeSafe {
    const SAVE_XSS = 1;
    const SAVE_SQL = 2;
    const SAVE_FILTER_HIGH = 4;
    const SAVE_FILTER_LOW = 8;
    const SAVE_FILTER = 16;

    private $options;

    function __construct($options) {
        $this->options = $options;
    }

    function escape($value) {
        if ($value = @mysql_real_escape_string($value))
            return $value;
        $return = '';
        for($i = 0; $i < strlen($value); ++ $i) {
            $char = $value[$i];
            $ord = ord($char);
            if ($char !== "'" && $char !== "\"" && $char !== '\\' && $ord >= 32 && $ord <= 126)
                $return .= $char;
            else
                $return .= '\\x' . dechex($ord);
        }
        return $return;
    }

    function parse($mixed) {
        if (is_string($mixed)) {
            $this->options & self::SAVE_XSS and $mixed = htmlspecialchars($mixed, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $this->options & self::SAVE_SQL and $mixed = $this->escape($mixed);
            $this->options & self::SAVE_FILTER_HIGH and $mixed = filter_var($mixed, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH);
            $this->options & self::SAVE_FILTER_LOW and $mixed = filter_var($mixed, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
            $this->options & self::SAVE_FILTER and $mixed = filter_var($mixed, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_HIGH | FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
            return $mixed;
        }

        if (is_array($mixed)) {
            $all = array();
            foreach ( $mixed as $data ) {
                $all[] = $this->parse($data);
            }
            return $all;
        }
        return $mixed;

        return $this->final;
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

Has i said i know this has been answered but i hope this helps someone else not to write code like yours ...

**PS : This has also fixed your PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset ERROR**

Comment: Indeed. I think I will implement the idea to my code - never used Dependency Injection before :) If you PM me your real name, I'd like to put your name in code as an author.

Comment: @Shehi how is the project going ?

Comment: @Bob: Good, I am upgrading it to PHP 5.3 and making some optimizations to it. I expanded your DI idea to three separate classes actually, separating Validation, Sanitation and UNicode for the moment. Still work in progress tho :)

Comment: @Bob: Sure, but you still have to gimme some name to put in code as co-author to some classes :) If not interested, ignore this request.

Comment: Sure, you welcome to fork it on Github. If it proves to be fruitful, in future I can have you in our JIRA environment, where I manage and run the project.
By the way, I am on upgrade-XXX branch on Github - once whole system is upgraded and tested, I will merge it into master branch.

Comment: [Pushed first version](https://github.com/olekukonko/SuperVariable) More filters coming with time

Comment: Can you email me at shehi@imanov.name please? I think we shouldn't communicate via comments here :)

Comment: Supperb..... I am trouble to much with this error.. but you are genius..

Answer (score 5):

I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191528/warning-illegal-string-offset-parameter-in-php-file). Apparently, the line

```
return $this->$name[ $this->clean__makesafe_key( $arguments[0] ) ] = $this->clean__makesafe_value( $GLOBALS[ $_name_of_superglobal ][ $arguments[0] ], array(), true );
```

should be like:

```
return $this->{$name}[ $this->clean__makesafe_key( $arguments[0] ) ] = $this->clean__makesafe_value( $GLOBALS[ $_name_of_superglobal ][ $arguments[0] ], array(), true );
```

due to the precedence.