# php redirect after success

Tags: php

How would you display a success message and then redirect in PHP. I've tried the 
`header("Location: .php");` but it does not display success message. If `header("Location: details1.php");` is taken out then success message does display but does not redirect. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: We can't help without seeing the code in question. You could redirect to a success page or have a refresh time. What research have you done?

Comment: The `Location` header tells the browser that the page can be found at another location. It does not make sense to show a success page *with* a `Location` header, because it will not be displayed.

Comment: You should consider using javascript instead of dealing with headers

Answer (score 1):

**Page1.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">

<?php

if($someCondition){
    header("Location: page2.php?message=someMessage");
    exit; // don't forget to exit
}

?>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Page2.php**

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="content">

<?php

if(isset($_GET['message']){ // NOTE: THE MESSAGE VAR CAN BE ANY NAME (NOT JUST MESSAGE). JUST MAKE SURE IT MATCHES THE NAME OF THE VARIABLE YOU SENT FROM PAGE1.PHP
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']);
    echo 'the message sent from redirection was: ' . $message;
}

?>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does header("Location: yourpage.php?var=some message"); go on the html page?

Comment: @Baba Out of curiosity, what would be the preferred way to make this safe against `xss` ? Just filtering the get input?

Comment: @Evan. Need a lot of help with php as im new to it. Could you help somehow?

Comment: @Evan use `htmlspecialchars` or this simple class [MakeSafe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15034807/1226894)

Comment: @user2216325 Yes, sure. I'll write a quick example.

Comment: @Evan. Thanks. I'm developing a application and struggling a lot. Would be great if i could show you the all my code to get it working somehow :s

Comment: @Evan. Thanks! I will give that a try. Could i email you for some help?

Comment: @user2216325 I'm not publicly displaying my email, and I don't have time to build an app for you, sorry. Feel free to open another question though.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use sessions when redirecting with a success/an error message:

**one.php**

```
$_SESSION['error'] = 'You lost the Game!';

header('Location: two.php');

exit;
```

**two.php**

```
if (isset($_SESSION['error']))
{

  echo $_SESSION['error'];

  unset($_SESSION['error']);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the meta refresh tag to redirect after a second or two:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://mysite.com/page.php">
```

---

You can pass the success message to the next page, too, and have it display it.

Comment: I tried that but it refreshes even if no username or password is typed in. I need it to redirect if username and password is correct.

Comment: This line replaces you header redirect.. You still need to do your validation logic, only echo this after displaying success.

Comment: How do i do that? Sorry i'm new to php. So the user logs in at login.html. Then it goes to login.php which displays if login was successful. I need it to redirect to another page if login was successful

Answer (score 0):

I use this PHP function

```
function redirects($URL,$msg,$secs){
    echo "<html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "<title> Cargando...</title>";
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content ='{$secs};url={$URL}'>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<b>{$msg}...</b></br>";
    echo "another message and link to go to the site" 
    echo "</br>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
}
```

of course you can style this.