# How to Solve warning in wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress

I m using wordpress directory theme in wordpress...now i m getting below warnings..how to remove them is there any problem with my code..I m getting warning in header files when I m clicking search function in my website..I m not sure what is wrong..and I m using wpdebug false in config file and how to remove this warning...can any one give me idea to resolve it..

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'field' in /home/travellm/public_html/listing/wp-content/themes/directory/header.php on line 27

Warning: Illegal string offset 'field' in /home/travellm/public_html/listing/wp-content/themes/directory/header.php on line 33
```

Below is my header code :

```
<?php



/**

 * AIT WordPress Theme

 *

 * Copyright (c) 2012, Affinity Information Technology, s.r.o. (http://ait-themes.com)

 */



global $aitThemeOptions, $latteParams, $wp_query, $registerErrors, $registerMessages;



// register form errors

if(isset($registerErrors)){

    $latteParams['registerErrors'] = $registerErrors->get_error_message();

}

// register form info

if(isset($registerMessages)){

    $latteParams['registerMessages'] = $registerMessages;

}



$mapCategory = 0;

$mapLocation = 0;

$mapSearch = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];

// parse tax query - only one category and location

if(isset($wp_query->tax_query)){

    $taxQueries = $wp_query->tax_query->queries;

    foreach ($taxQueries as $tax) {

        if($tax['field'] == 'id'){

            if($tax['taxonomy'] == 'ait-dir-item-category'){

                $mapCategory = (isset($tax['terms'][0])) ? $tax['terms'][0] : 0;

            } elseif ($tax['taxonomy'] == 'ait-dir-item-location') {

                $mapLocation = (isset($tax['terms'][0])) ? $tax['terms'][0] : 0;

            }

        } elseif ($tax['field'] == 'slug') {

            if($tax['taxonomy'] == 'ait-dir-item-category'){

                $mapCategory = (isset($tax['terms'][0])) ? get_term_by( 'slug', $tax['terms'][0], 'ait-dir-item-category' )->term_id : 0;

            } elseif ($tax['taxonomy'] == 'ait-dir-item-location') {

                $mapLocation = (isset($tax['terms'][0])) ? get_term_by( 'slug', $tax['terms'][0], 'ait-dir-item-location' )->term_id : 0;

            }

        }

    }

}

$latteParams['mapCategory'] = $mapCategory;

$latteParams['mapLocation'] = $mapLocation;

$latteParams['mapSearch'] = $mapSearch;



// for search form

$categories = get_terms('ait-dir-item-category', array(

    'hide_empty'        => false,

    'orderby'           => 'name'

));

$latteParams['categories'] = $categories;

$locations = get_terms('ait-dir-item-location', array(

    'hide_empty'        => false,

    'orderby'           => 'name'

));

$latteParams['locations'] = $locations;



// hierarchical autocomplete

if (isset($aitThemeOptions->search->searchCategoriesHierarchical)) {

    $hCategories = array();

    aitSortTermsHierarchicaly($categories, $hCategories);

    $latteParams['categoriesHierarchical'] = substr(aitGenerateHirerarchicalAutocomplete($hCategories), 0, -1);

}

if (isset($aitThemeOptions->search->searchLocationsHierarchical)) {

    $hLocations = array();

    aitSortTermsHierarchicaly($locations, $hLocations);

    $latteParams['locationsHierarchical'] = substr(aitGenerateHirerarchicalAutocomplete($hLocations), 0, -1);

}



// directory search

if(isset($_GET['dir-search'])){

    $latteParams['searchTerm'] = $wp_query->query_vars['s'];



    $latteParams['isGeolocation'] = (isset($_GET['geo'])) ? true : null;

    $latteParams['geolocationRadius'] = (isset($_GET['geo-radius'])) ? $_GET['geo-radius'] : 100;

    $latteParams['geolocationCircle'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->search->showAdvancedSearchRadius)) ? true : null;

    if(isset($aitThemeOptions->search->searchShowMap)){

        // map

        $latteParams['headerType'] = 'map';

        $radius = array();

        if(isset($_GET['geo'])){

            $radius[] = $_GET['geo-radius'];

            $radius[] = $_GET['geo-lat'];

            $radius[] = $_GET['geo-lng'];

        }

        $latteParams['items'] = getItems($_GET['categories'],$_GET['locations'],$wp_query->query_vars['s'],$radius);

    } else {

        $latteParams['headerType'] = 'none';

    }

} else if(isset($latteParams['isDirTaxonomy']) || isset($latteParams['isDirSingle'])){

    // map

    $latteParams['headerType'] = 'map';

    $latteParams['isGeolocation'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->enableGeolocation)) ? true : null;

    //$latteParams['geolocationOnlyInRadius'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationOnlyInRadius)) ? true : null;

    $latteParams['geolocationRadius'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationRadius)) ? $aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationRadius : 100;

    $latteParams['geolocationCircle'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationCircle)) ? true : null;

} else {

    // LOCAL

    if(!empty($latteParams['post']) && isset($latteParams['post']->options('header')->overrideGlobal)){

        $latteParams['headerType'] = $latteParams['post']->options('header')->headerType;

        switch ($latteParams['post']->options('header')->headerType) {

            case 'map':

                $latteParams['items'] = getItems();

                // geolocation

                $latteParams['isGeolocation'] = (isset($latteParams['post']->options('header')->enableGeolocation)) ? true : null;

                //$latteParams['geolocationOnlyInRadius'] = (isset($latteParams['post']->options('header')->geolocationOnlyInRadius)) ? true : null;

                $latteParams['geolocationRadius'] = (isset($latteParams['post']->options('header')->geolocationRadius)) ? $latteParams['post']->options('header')->geolocationRadius : 100;

                $latteParams['geolocationCircle'] = (isset($latteParams['post']->options('header')->geolocationCircle)) ? true : null;

                break;

            case 'image':

                $latteParams['headerImage'] = $latteParams['post']->options('header')->image;

                $latteParams['headerImageSize'] = aitGetImageSize($latteParams['post']->options('header')->image);

                break;

            case 'slider':

                $latteParams['headerSlider'] = $latteParams['post']->options('header')->slider;

                break;

            default:

                break;

        }

    // GLOBAL

    } else {

        $latteParams['headerType'] = $aitThemeOptions->header->headerType;

        switch ($aitThemeOptions->header->headerType) {

            case 'map':

                $latteParams['items'] = getItems();

                // geolocation

                $latteParams['isGeolocation'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->enableGeolocation)) ? true : null;

                //$latteParams['geolocationOnlyInRadius'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationOnlyInRadius)) ? true : null;

                $latteParams['geolocationRadius'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationRadius)) ? $aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationRadius : 100;

                $latteParams['geolocationCircle'] = (isset($aitThemeOptions->directoryMap->geolocationCircle)) ? true : null;

                break;

            case 'image':

                $latteParams['headerImage'] = $aitThemeOptions->header->image;

                $latteParams['headerImageSize'] = aitGetImageSize($aitThemeOptions->header->image);

                break;

            case 'slider': 

                $latteParams['headerSlider'] = $aitThemeOptions->header->slider;

                break;

            default:

                break;

        }

    }

}



WPLatte::createTemplate(basename(__FILE__, '.php'), $latteParams)->render();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Illegal string-offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906822/php-illegal-string-offset)

Comment: Did not understand for solution..can you tell me

Comment: Write `print_r($tax); die();` after `foreach ($taxQueries as $tax) {` and tell me what is outputing.